# Upcasting e downcasting subsequente permite acessar o atributo do tipo original?

Tags: c#, .net, herança, cast, polimorfismo

Quando faço um *upcasting*, o objeto 1 será convertido para o seu supertipo e é criado um objeto 2

Quando o objeto 1 é instanciado antes de fazer o *upcasting*, possui atributos que não existem na superclasse, ao criar o objeto 2, por meio do *upcasting*, vou ter nesse objeto 2 apenas os atributos da superclasse.

Na memória, ao criar esse objeto 2, no *heap* é realocado todos os componentes do objeto 1, e uma referencia para a cópia" é criada e um tipo referencia objeto 2 é feito, dessa forma, tudo que tinha no objeto 1 tem no heap no objeto 2, mas só consigo acessar a parte comum?

Quando existe sobreposição de métodos da superclasse e na subclasse, como o compilador consegue saber qual usar, quando existe esse *upcasting*? Imagino que o método que deveria valer seria o da superclasse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Upcasting*, pelo menos nessa situação, é apenas uma reinterpretação feita pelo compilador, ele passa entender o que acessar, sem mexer nada no objeto. É possível ter uma cópia do objeto por alguma operação, mas não pelo *casting*. A cópia manterá o mesmo objeto, não haverá perda de dados, e os dados da classe filha poderão ser acessados desde que se faça um *downcasting* no objeto.

Sobreposição é um termo ambíguo. Se um método for virtual e a classe filha sizer um `override` nele então é esse método que será executado sempre, desde que o objeto seja da classe filha.

Se o método não for virtual então o método a ser executado é o método do tipo que está interpretando, mesmo que o objeto seja da classe filha, se está interpretando como a mãe o método a ser usado será o da mãe.

É possível escrever um código demonstrando tudo isso:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var filha = new Filha();
        filha.y = 1;
        var mae = (Mae)filha;
        var filha2 = (Filha)mae;
        WriteLine(filha2.y);
        mae.Virtual();
        mae.Real();
        filha2.Virtual();
        filha2.Real();
    }
}

class Mae {
    public virtual void Virtual() => WriteLine("Mãe");
    public void Real() => WriteLine("Mãe");
}
class Filha : Mae {
    public int y;
    public override void Virtual() => WriteLine("Filha");
    public new void Real() => WriteLine("Filha");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9wgkeD). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vjgCgl). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/InheritanceCast.cs).

Answer (score 1):

Acho que tem um exemplo que consegui compreender melhor a parte de sobreposição. 
Existe uma superclasse figuras geométricas, dentro dessa superclasse tenho um método de calculo de área. Dessa superclasse, vão ser criadas subclasses, classe retângulo, classe triangulo e etc, cada uma com seu método de calculo de área com o modificador `override`. Quando crio uma figura geométrica

```
Triangulo triangulo = new Triangulo();
Quadrado quadrado = new Quadrado();
FiguraGeometrica figuraGenerica = new FiguraGeometrica();
FiguraGeometrica figuraGeometrica1 = (FiguraGeometrica)triangulo;
FiguraGeometrica figuraGeometrica2 = (FiguraGeometrica)quadrado;
```

O método de calculo de calculo de área do triangulo está em `figuraGeometrica1`, pois esse foi sobreposto ao método presente mas não está em `figuraGeometrica2`, uma vez que o metodo sobreposto nela é o do quadrado. Já em `figuraGenerica` o metodo de calculo de area é o metodo da superclasse.

Na questão de memoria, quando existe a operação de casting, down ou up, não são feitas alterações no objeto, uma referencia, um ponteiro, novo é criado apontando para o mesmo objeto e o compilador interpreta apenas aquilo que é presente na superclasse, ou seja, tudo que tinha no objeto da subclasse ainda existe, não é feita copia, apenas um novo ponteiro no stack é adicionado apontando para o mesmo objeto, dessa forma, o compilador consegue acessar os campos presentes apenas na superclasse, mas todas as outras informações estão presentes ainda.

Por exemplo, dentro da classe Quadrado existe um atributo que é valor da diagonal, mas  esse atributo não existe na superclasse:

```
FiguraGeometrica figuraGeometrica2 = (FiguraGeometrica)quadrado;
```

no upcasting, uma referencia figuraGeometrica2 é criada e aponta para o quadrado que está no Heap.

Ao realizar um downcasting

```
Quadrado quadrado2 = (Quadrado)FiguraGeometrica2;
```

um novo ponteiro é feito, e ele aponta para o mesmo lugar, so que agora o compilador é capaz de acessar o atributo da diagonal, que não foi apagado, estava lá o tempo todo, na mesma referencia.

Em resumo, os métodos quando se realiza casting são os métodos da própria classe, a menos que uma sobreposição tenha sido feita. Os atributos não desaparecem, ficam na mesma referencia só não podem mais ser acessados.

Acredito que seja isso !!!