# Porque eu faria Downcasting e Upcasting em C#

Tags: c#

Para ser mais específico, eu entendi os conceitos e tudo mais, porém eu não tenho um exemplo da vida real que eu precisaria fazer upcasting ou downcasting, por exemplo

BusinessAccount herda de Account

BusinessAccount : Account

```
Account ac1 = new BusinessAccount();
```

Porque eu faria isso, se é mais simples eu fazer

```
BusinessAccount ac2 = new BusinessAccount();
```

Comment: Relacionada: [Para que serve uma implementação explícita de interface em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/133957).

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/449584/upcasting-e-downcasting-subsequente-permite-acessar-o-atributo-do-tipo-original/449650#449650

Comment: O downcasting, na maior parte das vezes porque há erro de projeto. O mais comum quando explicam sobre isso ensinam projeta\r errado. Sim, boa parte das bibliotecas e frameworks que você usa tem erro de projeto. Quase sempre tem solução melhor se o projeto for bem feito. Algumas respostas abaixo ensinam fazer cast onde não precisa ou não ensinam fazer cast, ou falam de cast que não foi necessário fazer (a pergunta não ajuda). Estou sem tempo de elaborar um resposta completa. Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/286192/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131091/101.

Comment: Vou olhar todos os links e agradeço pelo esforço de ajudar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou usar os nomes das classes que colocou na pergunta. Temos as seguintes classes:

A classe base `Account`:

```
internal class Account
{
    internal int AccountNumber { get; set; }
}
```

E duas classes que herdam dela. Uma classe para contas empresariais:

```
internal class BusinessAccount : Account
{
    internal string BusinessName { get; set; }
    internal decimal Revenue { get; set; }
}
```

E uma para organizações:

```
internal class OrgAccount : Account
{
    internal string OrganizationName { get; set; }
}
```

As classes se diferem no quesito de propriedades, então podem ser usadas no código **para coisas mais específicas e diferentes entre si**.

Fazer um *downcasting* é útil no exemplo de um método `GetAccount(int accountNumber)` que pode retornar qualquer tipo de conta, seja ela `BusinessAccount` ou `OrganizationAccount`.

Porém, como cada uma se difere em suas propriedades, precisamos tratá-las de formas diferentes. Para isso podemos usar a seguinte conversão, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
// Não temos certeza de qual é o tipo que está retornando (Account, Business ou Organization)
Account account = GetAccount(accountNumber: 93840303);

// Verificando o tipo que retornou do método GetAccount
if (account is BusinessAccount) 
{
    // downcast para um tipo mais específico
    var businessAccount = (BusinessAccount)account;

    // recebe apenas o tipo BusinessAccount
    ManageBusinessAccount(businessAccount); 
} 
else if (account is OrganizationAccount) 
{
    // downcast para um tipo mais específico
    var orgAccount = (OrganizationAccount)account;

    // recebe apenas o tipo OrganizationAccount
    ManageOrganizationAccount(orgAccount);
} 
else 
{
    //...
}
```

Veja que **o *downcasting* é necessário neste cenário, dado que os métodos `ManageBusinessAccount` e `ManageOrganizationAccount` não recebem o tipo base como argumento**.

Mas caso tenhamos um método `ManageAccount` que recebe apenas o tipo base `Account` como argumento, podemos passar qualquer um dos tipos:

```
OrganizationAccount orgAccount = (OrganizationAccount)account;
ManageAccount(account); // Este método recebe apenas o tipo Account como argumento
```

Pois tanto o tipo `BusinessAccount` quanto o tipo `OrganizationAccount` implementam a classe base. Ou seja, **o upcasting é "implícito"**.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos ver se consigo te ajudar.

**Cenário:**

Imaginemos que você está desenvolvendo um jogo. Neste jogo você apresenta na tela alguns tipos de animais (Leão, Zebra, Homem, Sapo,Canguru, Etc). Todos esses animais herdam o comportamento **corre** da classe **Animal**. Logo teremos as seguintes definições.

```
public class Animal
{
   public virtual void corre(){}
}

public class Homem : Animal
{  
  public override void corre(){
      Console.WriteLine("Alternando Pernas");
  }
}

public class Sapo: Animal
{
   public override void corre(){
      Console.WriteLine("Pulando");
  }
}
```

ETC ...

Com essas definições imagine que na tela quando alguém estiver jogando você teria uma lista de animais correndo durante o jogo. Em vez de você percorrer uma lista específica de cada animal para apresentar os mesmos correndo, você poderia ter uma lista do tipo Animal contendo todos os animais que farão parte do cenário. Logo, para dar ação a todos os bichos vocÊ poderia ter o código abaixo:

```
var animais = new List<Animal> { new Homem(), new Sapo(), etc ... };

foreach (Animal a in animais )
{
    a.corre();
}
```

Isso seria suficiente para que todos os bichos se movessem na tela

Em vez de fazer:

```
 var homens= new List<Home> { new Homem(), new Homem(), etc ... };
 var sapos= new List<Sapo> { new Sapo(), new Sapo(), etc ... };  

foreach (homens in homem)
{
    homens.corre();
    sapos.corre();
}
```

O exemplo é puramente inslustrativo. Mas, o nome do conceito que você precisa entender é o polimorfismo e essa propriedade é utilizada para tratar os mais diversos problemas de modelagem. Tudo isso ficará mais claro quando você estudar padrões de projetos. Talvez o Strategy seja o mais simples de você entender o conceito do polimorfismo.

Espero ter ajudado.

**OBS:** Obviamente esse conceito não deve ser utilizado de maneira indiscriminada e de qualquer jeito. É muito comum a aplicação de polimorfismo junto com iterfaces.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta

Answer (score 1):

Vou dar um exemplo que não é específico de C# mas ocorre em todo framework com interface gráfica. Cada elemento na tela é uma `View`. Existem elementos compostos de subviews, ou seja, que contém objetos `View` subordinados. A própria janela é uma super `View` que contém direta ou indiretamente todas as outras.

Existem Views de diversos tipos: `TextView`, `ButtonView`, `ImageView`, `LabelView`... (os nomes exatos vão depender da linguagem e do framework). Todas essas classes descendem de `View` e compartilham uma implementação básica que lhes permite aparecer na tela.

Adicionar uma subview a uma `View` é um exemplo de "upcasting" - não interessa o tipo final da subview, ela é tratada pela view-pai como `View`, simplesmente.

Agora, outra situação: um tratador de evento recebe o objeto `View` que disparou o evento. Mas eu sei que esse objeto é na verdade um `ButtonView`, e como parte da resposta ao evento, quero chamar um método que só existe na classe `ButtonView`. Então tenho de fazer um "downcasting" de `View` para `ButtonView`.

Posso fazer isso inclusive de forma opcional, usando os operadores `is` ou `as` para testar se o downcasting vai dar certo, ou para lidar com o caso do objeto `View` poder ser de diversas sub-classes e o tratamento de evento deva se comportar diferente para cada sub-classe.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta